# Base Activity For All Activity

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to store some sensitive data such as JOSN TOKEN into Local Storage. My App will have Multiple Activities, I would like to check the Token Validity on every single activity, I dont want to copy/paste the same logic on all Activities. is there anyway I can have something like a base activity which has the logic and all other activities inherit from it?

Currently all my activities look like this...

```
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
    }
    public class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
    }
    public class ContentActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
    }
```

I am just looking for a easy to write logic once and have all activities re-use it.

Comment: create your own base class that inherits from `AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a base class which inherits from class `AppCompatActivity`.

```
[Activity(Label = "BaseActivity")]
public class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here

        Preferences.Set("my_key", "123456");
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        var myValue = Preferences.Get("my_key", "default_value");

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-------------> value is:  "+myValue);
    }
}
```

And make other activities extend from the `BaseActivity` ,for example:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : BaseActivity
{

    Button button;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

**update**

> so if I have a Menu, which I need to share on all activities, is there
> any concept for base layout as well?

If you want to add menu for your all activities, you can just add your menus in `BaseActivity`  ,
please refer to the following code:

1.create your menu (`mymenu.xml`)in folder `menu` in your `Resources` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="Item 1"/>
  <item android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:title="Item 2"/>
  <item android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:title="Item 3"/>
</menu>
```

2.modify `BaseActivity` as follows:

```
   public class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here

            Preferences.Set("my_key", "123456");
        }

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {

            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.mymenu, menu);

            return true;
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.item1:
                    //Do stuff for item1

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("--------> select item1");
                    return true;
                case Resource.Id.item2:
                    //Do stuff for item2
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("--------> select item2");
                    return true;
                case Resource.Id.item3:
                    //Do stuff for item3

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("--------> select item3");
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: great, so if I have a Menu, which I need to share on all activities, is there any concept for base layout as well? I only want to listen to Toolbar events on one Base Activity.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check the updated part of my reply.